# Where do I find a complete Volmet frequencies list for Europe?

Tags: radio-communications

Is there any website or ,even better, book to buy to get such frequencies?

Comment: VOLMET frequencies are published in the national AIP's. To my knowledge, there is no single official resource

Comment: List of [HF frequencies for VOLMET](http://dxinfocentre.com/volmet.htm) worldwide.

Comment: @ymb1 although, to be honest, we have a couple of well accepted resouce location questions (including one of mine) we probably have to decide if to make them "historical" (and this deserves a meta post)

Answer (score 1):

I have a list, you can download it here [VOLMETS](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=62665642143028659573).
I would really appreciate if you can help me confirm stations that are operational. Obviously depending on your location, receiver and antenna you will not receive all these.

The list is by no means 100% accurate and there may be stations that have ceased operations or are very sporadic in operation. Without others assisting it is impossible for me to verify each and every station.

Answer (score 0):

You can look it up on this link world wide also for europe.

[VOLMET](http://dxinfocentre.com/volmet-wx.htm)